# Uploading a directory to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to upload a directory to AWS S3 based on AWS [documentation here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadDirDotNet.html)

```
  TransferUtility directoryTransferUtility =
                new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1));


    directoryTransferUtility.UploadDirectory(directoryPath,
                                                     existingBucketName);
```

In order to use above API i need `RegionEndPoint` and `BucketName`.  Lets say i have path in the following format
`https://mybucketname.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mykey/`

How do i upload a directory to this path?

I know I can parse the path and get `RegionEndPoint` and `BucketName` and use those values in the API. But i was wondering is there any API method available which takes the above path and uploads the objects to that path? The path already contains bucketname and regionendpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the below object to do that. It returns Bucket, IsPathStyle, Key and Region.

```
Amazon.S3.Util.AmazonS3Uri
```

For more information click on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=S3/TS3UtilS3Uri.html&tocid=Amazon_S3_Util_AmazonS3Uri